# Issues with view_name in HyperlinkedRelatedField DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In DRF to use `HyperlinkedRelatedField` you need to provide view_name as argument which normally is `{model_name}-detail` , if you are using standard routers.

But what if you are not using `standard routers`, means I have defined custom routers so How this view name will work in that case ?

My urls looks like this :

```
# venue routers
venue_detail = venues.VenueViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
})

venue_list = venues.VenueViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'add_venue'
})

urlpatterns = [

    # venue urls
    url(r'^organization/(?P<organization_id>[0-9]+)/venue/$', 
        venue_list, 
        name='venue-list'),

    url(r'^organization/(?P<organization_id>[0-9]+)/venue/$', 
        venue_list, 
        name='venue-add'),

    url(r'^organization/(?P<organization_id>[0-9]+)/venue/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 
        venue_detail, 
        name='venue-detail'),

]
```

**Serializer :**

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    venue = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(queryset=Venue.objects.all(), view_name='venue-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = members.Members
        fields = ['id', 'venue', 'extra_info']
```

Comment: You _can_ combine the two. `urlpatterns = [ url(r'^', include(router.urls)), url(r'^organization/(?P<organization_id>[0-9]+)/venue/$', 
        venue_list, 
        name='venue-list'), [...]`  So if you'd like to use both standard Django urls and DRF-provided URLs, that is very much supported.

Comment: Could you please the error that you get using `view_name='venue-detail'` in the serializer field?

Comment: @zymud `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "venue-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the default serializers will not know about what `organization_id` is and thus this won't match the associated url.

First, I'd advice **not** to use nested routers or path.
If you want to view all the venues for a given organization, you should use [filters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) instead. For example:

```
https://xxxx/api/venue/?organization=somecorp
```

If you want still to go with nested routers you should try the [nested routers app](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers).

Alternatively you'll need to override the serializer's `get_url` to provide the `organization_id`.